# Conceptual question about constructible points of circle-line intersections in the context of field extensions

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, geometric-construction

In Chapter 30 of Pinter's "*A Book of Abstract Algebra*", the reader is introduced to the idea of constructible points (using a ruler and compass) and how they can be viewed in relation to *field extensions* and *vector spaces*. I have a conceptual question about the field extensions that are associated with constructible points **derived from the intersection of a line segment with a circle**

Besides the pictures I will provide below, the only necessary information is as follows:

1. Let $P$ be a constructible point within the the plane $\mathbb Q \times \mathbb Q$.
2. Suppose $P$ has coordinates $(a,b)$. We associate with $P$ the field $\mathbb Q (a,b)$, which is obtained by adjoining the coordinates of $P$ to $\mathbb Q$.
3. Let $K_1$ be the resulting field of $\mathbb Q (a,b)$...that is to say, $K_1 = \mathbb Q (a,b)$.
4. For each additional constructible point $P_i = (a_i,b_i)$ that is associated to a pre-existing $K_{i-1}$, let $K_i = K_{i-1}(a_i,b_i)$

With those in mind, here is the lemma and a portion of the accompanying proof which inspired the question:

> [image: Lemma]

I have outlined in $\color{#c00}{red}$ the portion of the proof that I want to focus on:

Specifically, if *Point $S$* is defined by the coordinates $(x_i,y_i)$ and *Point $T$* is defined by the coordinates $(x_j,y_j)$, in general, are the field extensions $K_{i-1}(x_i,y_i)$ and $K_{i-1}(x_j, y_j)$ equivalent? That is to say, there are two $x$ values that will serve as the roots of the quadratic polynomial that solve for points of intersection between the line and circle: $x_i$ and $x_j$. With their accompanying $y$ values ($y_i$ and $y_j$, respectively), are these two extensions, formed by associating **different but related** constructible points $S$ and $T$ to the same pre-existing field $K_{i-1}$ generally equivalent?

My intuition says *no*, besides two special cases:

Case 1: The line segment is coincident with a diameter line

Case 2: The line segment intersects the circle such that the interior angle is $90 \deg$

> [image: Circle Pics]

Any commentary is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you get the same extensions from both points. The reason is the structure of the solutions of the quadratic equation. Say for $x_i$ you get two solutions of the form
$$
x_i=\frac{-b\pm\sqrt{\Delta}}{2a}
$$
which both belong to **the same extension** $\mathbb{Q}\cup\{\sqrt{\Delta\}}$ (assuming there are real solutions of course). The same is true about $y_i$. Therefore, the extensions are the same.

Comment: ohhhh. So, said differently, if $x_i = \frac{-b + \sqrt \Delta}{2a}$ and $x_j=\frac{-b - \sqrt \Delta}{2a}$, then $|x_i - x_j| = \frac{1}{a}\sqrt\Delta$ which is effectively a linear combination of the form $k_0(1)+k_1(\sqrt\Delta)$ where $k_0=0$ and $k_1=\frac{1}{a}$. Therefore, if $x_i$ is in the extension, $x_j$ must correspondingly be in the extension. Is that correct?

Comment: Yes, that is correct. You extend your field by adding the same $\sqrt{\Delta}$ in both cases.